# 3d manipulator disappears in rendered view

Tags: 3d-view

When I switch from solid mode to rendered mode, my 3d manipulator diappears. I'm trying to create some interesting light effects, but because I can't see the rotation and transformation arrows, it isn't all too easy to position my sunlight. If someone could please tell me how to enable the 3d manipulator in rendered view, I would be much helped! I'm using blender 2.79b. I can see the effect the lamplight has on my scene, but I can't see the actual mesh. If I select a figure in my scene, I can rotate it and see the effect of the rotation, but I don't see the rotate manipulator in the viewport, nor do I see which object in my scene is selected until I start the rotation with the Rkey
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Clarification: what version of Blender is this referring to?

Comment: Is everything else showing, like the lamp?

Comment: I'm using blender 2.79b. I can see the effect the lamplight has on my scene, but I can't see the actual mesh. If I select a figure in my scene, I can rotate it and see the effect of the rotation, but I don't see the rotate manipulator in the viewport, nor do I see which object in my scene is selected until I start the rotation with the Rkey.

Comment: I would like to be able to change the light in rendered view as in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ICf9MgGt1Y. But in my case the selected object is invisible. Of course I'm not using the latest blender version, but I hope someone has a solution for me!

Comment: Is the rendered view really the only display mode in which shadows are displayed? If it is possible to enable shadows for the textured/solid view, I could position my lights much easier

Comment: If someone could please help me out!